# What's the most idiomatic way to implement a stack for `dictionary` type in `Python`?

Tags: python, dictionary, stack

I am trying to implement a stack machine in `Python` using `list` as my stack and `dictionary` as current machine state. But it doesn’t work as planned. After some debugging I found out that when I store machine state into stack, and then change it state, the stored state changes also.
Here is an example demonstrating my problem:

```
MyStack = []        
myState = {}
myState['param'] = '1'
MyStack.append(myState)
myState['param'] = '2'
MyStack.append(myState)
myState['param'] = '3'
MyStack.append(myState) 
print(MyStack.pop())
print(MyStack.pop())
print(MyStack.pop())
```

the result is:

```
{'param': '3'}
{'param': '3'}
{'param': '3'}
```

And not

```
{'param': '3'}
{'param': '2'}
{'param': '1'}
```

As I would think

Evidently, `Python` stores in `list` not copies of my `dictionary`, but references to it. So, all stacked items in reality are the same `myState` object. When I’ve got this, I walked the problem around by using `dictionary.copy()` method like so: `MyStack.append(myState.copy())`. But it seems a bit unnatural.

So, the question is: which is the most idiomatic way to implement a stack for `dictionary` type in `Python`?

Comment: "I found out that when I store machine state into stack, and then change it state, the stored state changes also." This is called "pass by reference." Basically, pushing the dict to the stack didn't copy the dict, it just stored a way to look up the same dict later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you are passing the same `myState` object inside `MyStack.append`, which gets updated every time rather than creating a new one. SO, inside the list you are always getting same identical element.

Let's see a data flow of your program.

```
MyStack = []        
myState = {}              # An empty dictionary 'myState' created 
myState['param'] = '1'    # 'mystate' -> {'param':'1'} 
MyStack.append(myState)   # 'MyStack' -> [mystate] -> [{'param':'1'}]
myState['param'] = '2'    # 'mystate' -> {'param':'2'} 
MyStack.append(myState)   # 'MyStack' -> [mystate,mystate ] 
                          #                       ->  [{'param':'2'},{'param':'2'}] 
myState['param'] = '3'    # 'mystate' -> {'param':'3'}
MyStack.append(myState)   # 'MyStack' -> [mystate,mystate, mystate] 
                          #        ->   [{'param':'3'},{'param':'3'},{'param':'3'}]
```

I hope, it is clear to you now.

How to solve this:

Ensure you are creating a new dictionary every time rather than using the same one.

Before `myState['param'] = '2'` and `myState['param'] = '3'`, just call,

```
myState = myState.copy()
```

Code:

```
MyStack = []        
myState = {}
myState['param'] = '1'
MyStack.append(myState)
myState = myState.copy()
myState['param'] = '2'
MyStack.append(myState)
myState = myState.copy()
myState['param'] = '3'
MyStack.append(myState) 
print(MyStack.pop())
print(MyStack.pop())
print(MyStack.pop())
```

Output:

```
{'param': '3'}
{'param': '2'}
{'param': '1'}
```